# C# Implicit get for field unit conversion

Tags: c#, attributes, implicit

I'd like to proper handle the unit for an given value (e.g double) for my shop system.

In the database its globally configured, which unit is actually used. The base unit is set by global config.

Now I like the implicitest way get my values from model.

What I like to avoid is the following:

```
    public class BadWay
    {
        private double _width;
        public double Width
        {
           get { return LengthConverter.Convert(_width, GlobalConfig.LengthConversionFactor); }
           set { _width = value; }
        }
      }
```

What I really would love:

```
    [LengthUnit]
    public double Width { get; set; }

    [WeightUnit]
    public double Weight { get; set; }
```

And in the Attribute everything is handled for conversion. 
I have already seen a discussion that this is a bad way.

I really like to know your ideas / libraries / solutions for this..

Comment: This is more or less what PostSharp can allow you to do. It seems what you're looking for is aspect-oriented programming, which isn't baked into C#.

Comment: Maybe you left something out but, I'm having trouble seeing the use of converting a double to a double.

Comment: @Kevin I am talking about units.  Millimetre to metre or something like this

Comment: Fair enough, that was not evident from your post.

Comment: Unit conversions require two pieces of information, value entered and units entered. If the units entered matches your base unit, no conversion is necessary. If not a conversion algorithm can be determined. To use declarative processing, you will need to pass your object to a converter that can read the attributes and determine which conversion algorithm to apply.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete How is this question off topic? The OP's question fits within the guidelines for an on-topic question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this all comes down to design principles. Yes you could do what you're thinking, but you'll still end up adding on a library or hardcoding in some conversions.

A common problem with design, is that we like to oversimplify things. Your properties can be thought of as double's, but thats not really what they are, they are units.

Then you can just have a class for each type of unit you mentioned above

```
public LengthUnit Width { get; set; }

public WeightUnit Weight { get; set; }
```

Each Unit class could inherit from an interface that provides whatever you need like Unit factor or converting to another unit.